# When the user entered an unauthorized url redirect to login page

Tags: plugins, theme-development, themes, login, account

I have custom account page for user, i want the users who are not logged in site when enter **http://example.com/account** redirected to a custom login page.

Here My code

```
function setup_user_panel_url()
{
   add_rewrite_rule('account', 'index.php?account=1', 'top');
   flush_rewrite_rules();
}

function check_request($query)
{
    if (isset($query->query_vars['account'])) {
      include USER_PANEL_VIEWS . 'panel.php';
      exit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello! Could you detail how are those functions being called?

Comment: You can check the user login status via `is_user_logged_in()` function and then redirect to the non-logged-on users to the custom login page via `wp_redirect('http://example.com/account')`.

Answer (score 0):

I should add **is_user_logged_in()** wordpress function. and check if user is not logged in site redirect user to home page with **wp_redirect(home_url())** function.

```
 if (isset($query->query_vars['account'])) {

    if (!is_user_logged_in()) {
        wp_redirect(home_url());
        exit();
    }

    include NABRO_USER_PANEL_VIEWS . 'panel.php';
    exit();
}
```